# SpreadsheetApp.insertImage server error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Why the below code return 'server error' in GSuite Spreadsheet?

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Wc6nKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0Ld6QyaY');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2018.0801-0831');
  var img = DriveApp.getFileById('1qw2uy3cNxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDZRES');
  var imgBlob = img.getBlob();
  sheet.insertImage(imgBlob, 9, 20);
}
```

The Image is JPEG, 276KB.
With an image its size is 173KB, this code is working.
Is it possible to insert large imageBlobs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, when an image is inserted by `insertImage()`, the limitation is due to the image area (pixels^2) rather than the file size of it. The maximum area of image which can be inserted is 1,048,576 pixels^2.

I have experimented as follows.

- Image with the following sizes can be inserted.

  - 1024 pixels x 1024 pixels
  - 2048 pixels x 512 pixels
  - 4096 pixels x 256 pixels
- Image with the following sizes can NOT be inserted.

  - 1025 pixels x 1025 pixels
  - 1024 pixels x 1025 pixels
  - 1025 pixels x 1024 pixels

From these results, I concluded the limitation for inserting image is 1,048,576 pixels^2.

So if the area of image you want to insert is more than 1,048,576 pixels^2, please resize it and try again.

Comment: Thank you for advice. It was really helpful. Image cannot be inserted is 3972 x 360, so I will resize it.

Comment: @Kentaro Usui I'm glad your issue was solved. Your question gave me a good chance to investigate the limitation. This is also useful for me. Thank you, too.