# What is the limits of insertInlineImage?

Tags: google-docs-api

We have randomly encountered a resolution limit of 25 megapixels when working with the Google Docs API, after a few search we found nothing in the API documentations mentioning any kind of limits.

What are the limits of adding inline images?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55466100

Comment: @Tanaike Not really, my question is really about an authoritative documentation on the said limits. Experimental evidences we can do ourselves but it’s not really helpful in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't find such document at the official document. So I investigated. But I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike Please don’t take it that way, I have to clarify this to prevent future deletion. Really appreciate your help!