# Is there a limit on the size of the blob for insertImage into a sheet (Google App Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am inserting images on my google drive into sheets via their **ID's.**

However, when executing the code it always throws:

*We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line XX, file "TestCodeV1.0")*

Where line XX has the code for ***insertImage(blobSource, column, row)***.

I have tested the FILE_ID of different images on my GDrive, and it works for images smaller or equal to **151 239 bytes**, (*img.getSize*). For images larger than that it just throws the same error.

I have tried adding a delay between *getFileByID* and *insertImage*, however, that did not help (Thought it might be a *'still loading image blob'* type of error).

I have tried to see if it is related to the images' pixel count or width/height.

The only factor seems to be the size (151 239 bytes)

```
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'YOUR_SHEET_ID_HERE'
var SHEET_NAME= 'YOUR_SHEET_NAME_HERE'
var FILE_ID= 'YOUR_IMAGE_ID_HERE'

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_URL);
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

var img = DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_ID).getBlob();
var image = sheet.insertImage(img, 1,1);
```

I expected the images the work be inserted easily. However, any image larger than 147KB failed with an error:
***"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."***

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244712/spreadsheetapp-insertimage-server-error/51255496#51255496

Comment: I believe that is the reason thanks @Tanaike!

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, I'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) - 
Find full explanation [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255496/11546984)

**Summary**

Images that are inserted with ***insertImage()*** must have a pixel area less than **1 048 576 px^2**

Some examples of maximum pixel dimenions:

- 1024 pixels x 1024 pixels
- 2048 pixels x 512 pixels
- 4096 pixels x 256 pixels