# Service Error when trying to use .insertImage off of an input type='file' capture='camera' in Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, blob, input-type-file, insert-image

I've tried calling the image a number of different ways and get the same error on the .insertImage each time (Service Error: Spreadsheets).  I'm wondering if it has to do with the format of the image since it is gathered from a file upload of a mobile camera picture.  The blob is saved in the specified folder and the image looks great, but it won't load into the spreadsheet like I need it to.  Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.25, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable:no"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    img {
      height: auto;
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <br>
     Control Number:<br>
     <input type="number" id="control">
     Take Picture:<br>
     <input type="file" id="takePic" onchange="previewFile();" accept="image/*" capture="camera"><br>
     <img src="" class="preview" alt="Image preview..." style="display:none;">
     <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none;">
     
  </body>
  <script>
  function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('img');
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
          preview.src = reader.result;
      }, false);    
    
    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      $('.preview').show();
      $('#submit').show();
      }
    else {
      $('.preview').hide();
      $('#submit').hide();
      }
    }
  $('#submit').click(function(){
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var control = $('#control').val();
    var data;
    
    if(file){
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
      
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).withFailureHandler(failure).saveImage(reader.result, control)
      }, false);
    });
  function failure(x){
    alert(x);
    }
  function success(x){
    alert("Successfully added");
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

.gs

```
function saveImage(data,name){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1nJBIq-EvzxIk9FP40diojuLKob46q4-w');
  var bytes = data.split(",");
  var base = Utilities.base64Decode(bytes[1]);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(base, 'image/jpeg', name);
  var url = folder.createFile(blob).getUrl();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = response.getContent();
  var img = Utilities.newBlob(data, 'image/jpeg', name);
  sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('Test');
  var test = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  test.insertImage(img, 1, 1).setWidth(200).setHeight(100); //error on this line
}
```

Comment: What is the file size of the image?

Comment: I've tried it with several different sized images, as small as 39kb.  The goal is to have pictures from a mobile camera be uploaded.  Is there a way to shrink the size of the file while it's in blob form?  That aside, I received the Service Error even on the 39kb.

Comment: for now I only have a couple of ideas, 1. Instead of inserting the image to a new sheet, try inserting to one created in advance and/or use SpreasheetApp.flush() before inserting the image.

Comment: Related [Insert an image into Google Spresheet Cell from Drive using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61471256/1595451)

Comment: Resizing the image with the ImgApp library worked perfectly!  Thank you, Rubén!

Comment: If you didn't it yet, please upvote Tanaike's answer. Also consider to mark this question as duplicate th the referred Q/A or to post an answer here describing how your code was fixed.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate and upvoted Tanaike's answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Rubén Curious. Why didn't you mark it as duplicate?

Comment: @TheMaster I don't remember exactly, maybe because I was using tmy mobile.